# Jquery validator not working with empty form submission

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Registration Form Using jQuery - Demo Preview</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="myForm">
    FirstName :
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="fname" minlength="3" id="fname" required>
    <br>LastName :
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" minlength="3" required>
    <br>Email :
    <br>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
    <br>URL :
    <br>
    <input type="url" name="url" id="url">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" class="submit">
  </form>
  <script>
    $("#myForm").validate();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

It is just similar to the first form of http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/
It works fine when I entered text in the fields, but when I submit the empty form then Its not giving the validation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your submit button must be a `type="submit"` if you want validation triggered when it's clicked.

```
<input type="submit" ....
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Registration Form Using jQuery - Demo Preview</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="myForm">
    FirstName :
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="fname" minlength="3" id="fname" required>
    <br>LastName :
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" minlength="3" required>
    <br>Email :
    <br>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
    <br>URL :
    <br>
    <input type="url" name="url" id="url">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit">
  </form>
  <script>
    $("#myForm").validate();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```